# Can you use Lambert's W to solve this equation for x?

Tags: lambert-w

I would like to solve the following equation for $x$:
$$
a= \left( \frac{x}{1-x} \right)^\lambda e^{bx}
$$
I'm fairly new to using Lambert's W so I'm not sure if this is an appropriate tool for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some simplifications the equation can be transformed into an equation of the form $A + B y = y e^y$ and I'm pretty sure that this equation can't be solved using the Lambert function (unless $A=0$ or $B=0$, of course).

I've solved many equations using the Lambert function and Mathematica always have been able to solve it too. For this one Mathematica wasn't able solve it.

Comment: I believe you are correct.  Maple (which does well with the Lambert W function) does not solve $1+y=ye^y$.  In the OP, the case $\lambda = 1, b=1$ is not solved by Maple.